# Subwavelength aperture vs microwave oven mesh

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves

I am trying to understand why some subwavelength apertures radiate such as https://lo.epfl.ch/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/OE_14_10410_Oct2006.pdf and why others don't. For eg. the mesh inside a microwave oven is also subwavelength but does not allow any leakage through the holes.
Can anyone provide some insight into this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: No, it isn’t that your microwave doesn’t emit any radiation, it just doesn’t emit more than is allowed.